# Writing a sentence with ば〜ほど

Tags: grammar, meaning, words, sentence

時間が立てば立てるほど、頑張るのが一番大切なことがわかります。

I want to say something like: The more time passes, the more I understand that the most important thing is working hard.

Is my sentence in any way correct? Did I use ば〜ほど right?

Thank you

Comment: The verb for *to pass* is 経つ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 時間が立てば**立てる**ほど、頑張るのが一番大切なことがわかります。
>   The more time passes, the more I understand that the most important thing is working hard.

Use the dictionary form (or, the attributive form) [経]{た}つ, as in 経てば**経つ**ほど, not 経てば経てるほど. ([経]{た}てる is the potential form of 経つ.)

「時間が経てば経つほど、頑張るのが一番大切なことがわかります。」 would make sense, but to sound more natural (avoiding using が twice) I think you could say...

> 「時間が経てば経つほど、頑張る｛のが / ことが｝一番大切だと｛わかります / わかってきます｝。」
>   「時間が経てば経つほど、頑張るのが一番大切なことだと｛わかります / わかってきます｝。」

Alternatively, you could use 「Verb + につれ(て)」, for example:

> 「時間が**経つにつれ**、一番大切なのは頑張ることだとわかってきます。」

Comment: Yes, I absolutely made a mistake in the choice of the kanji and in writing たてる instead of たつ. Thank you for pointing that out. Thank you very much for your suggestions :) I can safely say that you taught me something new :)

Answer (score 1):

> The more time passes, the more I understand that the most

I think this translation is perfect.
But I think the Japanese part 時間が*立*てば*立てる*ほど looks and sounds weird and I wonder the 時間 is denoting whether "the time in your life" or "the time your effort is put in".

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the kanji you used for 「たつ」is incorrect. The kanji for "passing by" is 「経つ」.

Secondly, 「時間」refers more to a specific amount of time, where as 「時」(とき), refers more to time in general.

So I think a better sentence would be:

時が経てば経つほど、頑張るのが一番大事な物だと分かります。